# live caption is not available right now

Tags: google-chrome

It's been more than a month that my Chrome's live caption is not working....just writes:

"live caption is not available right now"

[live caption is not available right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmFp2.png)

I tried it with another computer, it worked there

I have removed and reinstalled my Chrome but the problem still exists

I want to say that previously it used to work.

I am using the latest version of Win 10 and the latest version of Chrome

Do you know how can I fix the problem?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10538231?hl=en

Comment: I know how to turn on google caption (I said previously it used to work)  but it is not working now just writes:"live caption is not available right now"

Comment: I signed in with a different Microsoft account on my computer and it worked, what is the problem with my current logged in account? how could I solve the problem?